# Timestamp issue from ojdbc5 & ojdbc

Tags: java, ojdbc

**JVM Timezone details :** India Standard TimeAsia/Calcutta019800000

**DB Timezone details :** Central Standard TimeAmerica/Chicago3600000-21600000

Sample Code:

```
String sql = "select systimestamp as base from dual";
....
PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement(sql);
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();
while(rs.next()) {
    System.out.println(rs.getTimestamp("base"));
    System.out.println(rs.getString("base"));
}
```

Test-1: 
I tested using ojdbc14.jar 10.1.0.3.0 with, it works as expected printing the db time

Output:

```
2013-12-05 01:23:57.141583 
2013-12-5 1.23.57.141583000 -6:0
```

Test-2: 
I tested using ojdbc5.jar & ojdbc6.jar 11.2.0.3.0 with, getTimestamp print local time where as getString prints db time.

Output:

```
2013-12-05 12:57:54.3508 
2013-12-05 01:27:54.3508 -6:00
```

Please suggest what is wrong with Test-2 ojdbc driver version 11.2.0.3.0 where the getTimestamp() prints local time. My application expect the db time like Test-1 in the getTimestamp() where it matches with DB timestamp.

Answer (score 1):

We had the same issue a few days ago at my company. The bottom line of this is you should never get a timestamp as a string (as it's database/driver specific) and always get the TimeStamp object and format it any way you want using a `SimpleDateFormat`.

And it's always worth mentioning that the Timestamp class is an abomination , from the [javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html)

> Due to the differences between the Timestamp class and the
>   java.util.Date class mentioned above, it is recommended that code not
>   view Timestamp values generically as an instance of java.util.Date.
>   The inheritance relationship between Timestamp and java.util.Date
>   really denotes implementation inheritance, and not type inheritance.

Comment: I use getTimestamp() in my code. The problem is, I get different time in 10g and 11g ojdbc drivers. In 10g, I used get the DB server time. Now I am getting the local time in 11g. That's what you can see the difference in my test. Why is the difference in time ?

Comment: Upz, I missed that. Can you print out the value of `rs.getTimestamp("base").getTime()`? Is the column a `TIMESTAMP` or one of the variations `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` or `TIMESTAMP WITH LOCAL TIME ZONE`?

Comment: Timezone details :India Standard TimeAsia/Calcutta019800000
getTimestamp(base) --> 2013-12-05 18:43:45.004413
getTimestamp(base).getTime() --> 1386249225004
getString(base) --> 2013-12-05 07:13:45.004413 -6:00                 SQL- "select systimestamp as base from dual"

Comment: I meant to do a `rs.getTimestamp("base").getTime()` with both versions of the driver. Don't bother about the string representation as it's driver specific and useless.

Comment: It requires lot of code changes in our application. Any other way can we manage without code change? We have to use ojdbc6.jar (from ojdbc14.jar) for our requirement. After that upgrade, we are facing this issue.